# Javascript url action in razor view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a javascript method `onRowSelected` wchich gets rowid. How to pass the rowid in certain action of a controller with `HttpGet`?

```
function onRowSelected(rowid, status) {
        alert('This row has id: ' + rowid);
        //url: @Action.Url("Action","Controller")
        //post:"GET"
        // Something like this?
    }
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If your controller action expects an id query string parameter:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")?id=' + rowid;
```

or if you want to pass it as part of the route you could use replace:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { id = "_id_" })'
    .replace('_id_', rowid);
```

yet another possibility if you are going to send an AJAX request is to pass it as part of the POST body:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { id: rowid },
    success: function(result) {

    }
});
```

or as a query string parameter if you are using GET:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { id: rowid },
    success: function(result) {

    }
});
```

All those suppose that your controller action takes an id parameter of course:

```
public ActionResult Action(string id)
{
    ...
}
```

So as you can see many ways to achieve the same goal.

Comment: I wonder why the first answer isn't working. The ajax answers works well.

Comment: No event is triggered even in firebug. The URL doesn't change.

Comment: What is the generated URL in your HTML? Right click in your browser and view source. Also what are you doing with the `url` variable next if you are not sending an AJAX request? How do you expect the browser to navigate away from the current page? What code you have written? I cannot read your mind.

Comment: I tired using `$.get(url, function (result)){ }` . I found my mistake, it was silly that i didn't create resultholder. Now it works. Thank you.

Comment: i really wonder why any of the options above will work? `@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")` is razor syntax. JavasScript (i.e `onRowSelected` event handler) will get executed in the browser which does know anything about `@Url.Action`.  Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The method by Darin will work fine and perfectly.

I would suggest one more way for Razor view to use model value using `@Html.actionlink` in jsp

```
var URLvalue='@Html.ActionLink("UserString", "action", new { routeValueName1 = "__value1__", routeValueName2="__value2__" }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-default", @role = "button" })'
     .replace('__value1__', Model.somevalue).replace('__value2__',  Model.somevalue);
```

you can use URLvalue where ever you want to in jsp or jquery.