# ASP.NET MVC: Redirecting from one view to another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, redirect

Hi I am using the following code to redirect from a kendo grid to another page (View):

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<WM.ViewModels.StockReceiptsGridViewModel>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Template("<a class='k-button k-button-icontext' onclick='addMaterialPopup()' href='#'></span>Create Stock Receipt</a>"))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.StockReceiptID);
        columns.Bound(p => p.SupplierName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Product);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Dimensions);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Quantity);
        columns.Bound(p => p.QuantityReserved);
        columns.Bound(p => p.PurchaseNumber);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Cost);
        columns.Bound(p => p.PhotosLink).Title("").ClientTemplate("<a href='/Photos/index?StockReceiptID=#=StockReceiptID#'>#=GetText()#</a>");
        columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Edit").Click("editreceipt"));

    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(false)
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.StockReceiptID))
                    .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "StockReceiptsGrid").Data("ExtraData"))
  )
)
```

**Javascript:**

```
function editreceipt(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var stockReceiptId = dataItem.StockReceiptID;

    window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Update","StockReceipt")"+"/"+stockReceiptId; // Problem code...

    }
```

The receiving method on the StockReceipt Controller is:

```
public ActionResult Update(int stockReceiptId)
{
   var stockReceipt = _stockReceiptRepository.GetAllStockReceipts().ToList().Where(r => r.StockReceiptID == stockReceiptId);

    var model = new StockReceiptViewModel();


    model.Notes = stockReceipt.First().Notes;



    return View("Index", model);
}
```

And here is my route configuration:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

**The Problem:**

.. is that the above Javascript code is not redirecting, it is taking me to this URL: http:`//localhost:50439/StockReceipt/6`

And reporting the 'Yellow Screen of Death' with this error:

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'stockReceiptId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Update(Int32)' in 'WorcesterMarble.Controllers.StockReceiptController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Where 6 is the ID.

If I remove the id element to become like this:

```
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Update","StockReceipt")"
```

It works, but I need the ID because I want to load the selected 'ViewModel' in the destination view.

I wonder what am I doing wrong?!

I have tried using this, but to no avail.:

```
window.location.href = @Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { @Controller = "StockReceipt", @Action = "Update"}) + '//' + stockReceiptId;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved like this:

```
function editreceipt(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var stockReceiptId = dataItem.StockReceiptID;

    window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Update","StockReceipt")?stockReceiptId=" + stockReceiptId; 
    }
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599995/javascript-url-action-in-razor-view)

Comment: Model binding will indeed pick up querystring variables and use them to hydrate your model, but I always found that sort of construction a bit odd. You build half your URL with MVC, and the other half with javascript concatenation. Why not let MVC do all the heavy lifting?

Comment: @ChrisHardie because I am using KendoUI grid. Navigation starts from  the Javascript click event on a custom button in the KendoGrid. As you see above, on click of the button I am capturing the ID of the selected record and then handing that ID over to the MVC url helper. Please let me know if there is any better way of doing this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I believe all you are looking for is this:

```
 window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Update","StockReceipt", new { id = 6 })"
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505151%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: In your default route your variable parameter is called id, so if you do not specify the variable name it will fall back to id.
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
This will also work "@Url.Action("Update","StockReceipt", new { stockReceiptId = 6 })"