# How can I get the data from a Kendo grid selected row when using server binding?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid with a button on each row, which I want to trigger a URL action to download a PDF file when clicked. In order to do this I need to pass the data ID to the URL action, but I am having a lot of trouble getting a reference to it. This is my table definition:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.revisions)
                    .Name("RevisionsGrid")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(p => p.RevisionInfo.RevisionDate).Title("Date Modified");
                        columns.Bound(p => p.RevisionInfo.User.Name).Title("By User");
                        columns.Command(command => command.Custom("ViewPdf").Text("View PDF").Click("getPdf"));
                    })
                    .Sortable()
                    .Selectable()
                    .Events(e => e.Change("selection_change"))
                    .Pageable(p => p.PageSizes(new[] { 5, 10, 25 }))
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Server()
                    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.RevisionInfo.Id)))
```

I need a reference to the model's RevisionInfo.Id. I do not want to change this to Ajax binding.

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337608/asp-net-mvc-redirecting-from-one-view-to-another) but `this.dataItem` always returns null. I also tried using a reference to the Kendo grid instead of `this` with the same result.

```
function getPdf(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var revisionId= dataItem.RevisionId;

    window.location.href = "@Url.Action("GetPdf","Reports")?revisionId=" + revisionId; 
    }
```

This seems like it should be simple but I'm at a loss. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You missed the kendo grid element when querying the dataitem:

```
function getPdf(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var dataItem = $("#RevisionsGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
   var revisionId= dataItem.RevisionId;

   window.location.href = "@Url.Action("GetPdf","Reports")?revisionId=" + revisionId; 
}
```

Good luck!