# Call an ASP.NET MVC application's URL from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC. After reading many different examples I still can't get this done.

I have some JS scripts bundled and one out of the bundle (because I'm using a different main script per page)

```
(_Layout.cshtml)

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatables")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

And in my view

```
(index.cshtml)

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/index.js")"></script>
}
```

In javascript code I am trying to call a specific URL of my application

```
(index.js)

$('#table').DataTable({
    ajax: '@Url.Action("List", "Documents")'
});
```

Of course in my application a controller is definend with the name DocumentsController and with a List method, returning the correct JSON.

Still it seems no-one is ever replacing my url

[image]

If I include my index.js in the bundle, nothing changes.
Where is the mistake?
Who and when is replacing that URL?

Thank you

Comment: please show your controller code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Razor code inside a `*.js` file because they're served directly as static files and aren't processed by ASP.NET (nor `*.ts` files because they're transpiled to `*.js` at build-time).

What you can do instead is to render Razor-generated JavaScript in your View/Page and have your TypeScript or JavaScript expect that data to be available.

Like so:

#### Index.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var scriptUrls = {
    listDocuments: '@Url.Action("List", "Documents")';
};
</script>
```

#### Index.ts (if using TypeScript)

```
interface PageUrls {
    readonly listDocuments: string;
};

declare var scriptUrls: PageUrls;

//

$('#table').DataTable({
    ajax: scriptUrls.listDocuments
});
```

#### Index.js

```
$('#table').DataTable({
    ajax: scriptUrls.listDocuments
});
```

Comment: I think you're wrong, look here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599995/javascript-url-action-in-razor-view)

Comment: @AmirNorouzpour The link you pointed to is for a `<script>` element *inside* a `.cshtml` file. Whereas my answer for this question is for when the script is inside a separate `*.js` file.

Comment: Ok, now it's clear. I did assume that code was in js file. thank you.